# Separate a <div>'s content to print with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, web

This is on Mac OS X, Chrome 35 (but probably should apply elsewhere, too):

I need to print the contents of a webpage/webshop that is hidden behind/under a [rather unlucky div construct.](http://www.edelstahlschornstein-shop.de/Produktgruppe.aspx?VariantenID=3&DurchmesserID=12&ProduktgruppeID=82).

Is there a way to "extract" the contents of the `div` that contain the pricelist to make it printable all at once? I guess this might come in handy a couple of other times, too.

So far I have looked into Chrome's "Element untersuchen" ("Inspect element" I suppose), I have noticed that the contents are within a `div`, but I cannot extract them.

Comment: The linked site is gone. The link is now dead.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the contents of the `<div>` with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> (or <kbd>Command</kbd>, if you're on a Mac) + <kbd>C</kbd>.

Then, you can open up your preferred plain text editor (like TextWrangler or Notepad) and paste the contents in there. Then, save it as `ANYNAMEYOUWANT.html` to the Desktop or any readable, non-hidden location. Make sure you keep the `.html` extension.

Then, go to the location you saved it in, right click and choose "Open With" and then select Google Chrome from the popup that shows up.

Then, once the file has opened in Chrome, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> (or <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, and print the document.

Styles will not show up, but that's a problem when printing almost any webpage.